# DOMPDF not working for data:image on one computer, fine on another

Tags: php, dompdf, data-uri, data-url

I have a bit of an interesting one here. In our team there are 2 people working on one project on macs, both using MAMP Pro and the same codebase, why then is it that one machine can happily produce PDF documents with images in in the `data:image...` format and the other one can't?

Both can see the data uri and both can generate the html with it in, both are happy with normal images but one of them throws an error: `file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty` error.

I'm at a loss with this so can anyone please shed some light on it?

Many thanks everyone,
Gareth

Comment: Where does that error occur (file/line #)? Does the computer have read/write access to the temporary directory (DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR)? Are the systems set up the same (same version of PHP, GD, etc)?

Comment: If you would be so kind as to post that as an answer please I will upvote and accept it. It was permissions on the temporary directory. Would never have guessed that in a month of Sundays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick requirements for image processing:

1. Read/Write access to DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR
2. Availability of the GD PHP extension
3. For images fetched via web server, allow_url_fopen enabled

Comment: I have printed out DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR and it's: "/var/folders/2h/plj8jsnj7r1gglnsktbgr6_c0000gn/T", but where can I find this folder to provide access?

Comment: That would be on your server's file system. You would need to have shell or SFTP access to check or modify the permissions. Or you could just modify the value of `DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR` to point to a directory you have more control over.